# Xamarin Forms How can I inject a ContentPage into Frame element?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to inject  a ContentPage into Frame element ?

Is this possible to be done ?

I have update my description and I have added the below code

**XAML Code**

```
<navigationdrawer:SfNavigationDrawer x:Name="navigationDrawer" 
                                         DrawerWidth ="400" 
                                         Position="Right"
                                         BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource DynamicContentPageBackgroundColor}"
                                         DrawerHeaderHeight="160">
        <navigationdrawer:SfNavigationDrawer.ContentView>

            <Grid x:Name="mainContentView" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource DynamicContentPageBackgroundColor}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource DynamicContentPageBackgroundColor}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <controls:IconButton  Text="{i18n:TransIcn HamburgerMenu}" FontSize="30" x:Name="SyncIcon"  HorizontalOptions="Start"  Clicked="hamburgerButton_Clicked" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="#FFFFFF" ></controls:IconButton>
                    <Label x:Name="headerLabel"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="" FontSize="16"/>
                </StackLayout>

                <ScrollView Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                    <Frame x:Name="contentViewFrame" >
                    </Frame>
                </ScrollView>
            </Grid>
        </navigationdrawer:SfNavigationDrawer.ContentView>
        <navigationdrawer:SfNavigationDrawer.DrawerHeaderView>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource DynamicContentPageBackgroundColor}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--<Image Source="icon.png" HeightRequest="110"  BackgroundColor="#1aa1d6" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>-->
                <Label Text="James Pollock" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="20" TextColor="White"/>
            </Grid>
        </navigationdrawer:SfNavigationDrawer.DrawerHeaderView>
        <navigationdrawer:SfNavigationDrawer.DrawerContentView>
            <ListView x:Name="listView"
                      FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                      BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource DynamicContentPageBackgroundColor}"
                      ItemSelected="listView_ItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,8,0,0"  BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource DashboardItemsDarkSurface}">
                                <Label Text="{Binding IconText}"  HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="30" Style="{StaticResource EventaIconStyle}" ></Label>
                                <Label  Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalOptions="Start" Style="{StaticResource MainHeaderLabel}"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </navigationdrawer:SfNavigationDrawer.DrawerContentView>
        <navigationdrawer:SfNavigationDrawer.DrawerFooterView>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource DynamicContentPageBackgroundColor}" >
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" 
            `enter code here`         HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Footer View"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </navigationdrawer:SfNavigationDrawer.DrawerFooterView></navigationdrawer:SfNavigationDrawer>
```

Please Let me know if you need more information.

The issue is that I cannot add a ContentPage Object into the ContentView item so could please provide me with some workarounds that I might go for ?

Comment: No.  You can place a ContentView inside of a Frame, but not a ContentPage.

Comment: Thanks @Jason The issue is I have a Navigation Drawer and I would like to inject my content page into it. can I achieve it without using frame element ?

Comment: NavigationDrawer is not a standard XF control.  You need to be more specific about what you mean.

Comment: I am trying to use syncfusion NavigationDrawer  and at the it's content it takes a ContentView Items so I have added a frame and I am injecting Content Views but  I am looking to have my Content to be as ContentPage Type.

Comment: well, if NavigationDrawer requires a ContenView then you can't use a ContentPage.  You could create put everything in a ContentView and then include that inside of a ContentPage

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example if possible.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview

Comment: Thanks @Jason, I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

As they have been mentioning in the comments about a content VIEW vs content page, that should work for you with a slight bit of alteration.  When I wrote my first Xamarin app, I had several other applications over time that have had nested controls in controls and did not want to find myself in similar.

So, what I did was to create simple user controls with all the stuff I needed on them.  So when I was creating a page, I would just add my user control where it physically needed to be placed.  This way, should I need to alter the layout of that one user control, it doesn't change the functionality the rest of the way through.  Binding was the same because the binding context was the same level, regardless of the VISUAL depth of controls.

So, if you were to create a new Navigation drawer user control of its own context, then slap that in your content page should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will take your advise in considerations.